# Difference between 事業, 企業, and 会社?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

They all translate to the same thing: business, enterprise, etc. Most sentences I've found online seem to use them interchangeably (at least, as far as I can tell), and they are all very common words. An entry for any of the given words in a monolingual dictionary uses one of the other two in the definition, which is really annoying.

So what is the difference between 事業, 企業, and 会社?

Comment: There are probably others that I'm forgetting, so if you think of any other words that mean nearly the same thing as these please include them as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my understanding

- 事業 is more like a specific job that a person does for a company or the specific task or service that a company can perform.
- 企業 can be more specifically translated as "enterprise"... like "Enterprise Technology and Services". You wouldn't say "the 企業　that I work at".
- 会社 is the general term for a business or your place of work. "My company". ie: 株式会社 = a corporation.

職場 (workplace) or 仕事　(job) can be used in place of 会社 in certain situations like:

- He's still at work. まだ会社（職場）に居ます。
- He quit his job. 会社（仕事）を辞めた。

法人 can also mean "Enterprise" or "Business" similarly to 企業 but is usually used to differentiate between a service or rule that applies to companies rather than individuals (個人）

I'll try to add more 類語 as I think of them.